# Python: slices of enumerate

Tags: python, list, slice

I want to iterate within a slice of a list.
Also, I want to know the indexes of the element under my iteration.

I want to make something like

```
for i, elm in enumerate(test_list)[7:40]:
    print i, elm
    #i must start with 7
```

Alas, it says, that `'enumerate' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

How can I get it in most pythonic way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

for i,elm in islice(enumerate(some_list),7,40):
    print i,elm
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer because it doesn't require typing the start position of the slice twice.

Comment: However, it does consume the first elements of the list, so if you start at index 100, it will iterate over 100 elements first. Slicing the list instead will just *jump* there.

Comment: @poke Indeed, but slicing also creates a temporary list in memory.  Both have their performance upsides.

Comment: @roippi, but since ```enumerate()``` is an iterator isn't the impact more significant?

Comment: @wnnmaw that is difficult to answer, both are faster in some situations.  Almost never is either going to be close to a performance bottleneck, so really choosing one for its performance characteristics is premature optimization.

Comment: @roippi, fair enough.  I guess since a list is already in memory it doesn't seem as bad to make a temp copy, whereas your iterator is generating data and then tossing it.  It just seems to go against the principle of why you'd want to use iterators to begin with

Answer (score 15):

`enumerate` returns an iterator, which does not support index-based access. You can however slice the original list first, and just start at a different index with `enumerate`:

```
for i, elm in enumerate(test_list[7:40], 7):
    print i, elm
```